# How to consume messages selectively from Spring AMQP?

Tags: rabbitmq, message-queue, producer-consumer, spring-jms, spring-amqp

In the queue I have pushed 10K objects. Timestamp is one of the attribute in object. So, how can I write a consumer code using spring amqp?

can anyone help me on this.

Answer (score 2):

AMQP, unlike JMS, has no notion of message selection for consumers. One solution is to use a topic exchange and set the routing key - let's say consumer 1 binds his queue to the exchange with `foo.bar` a second one binds with `foo.baz`; and a third binds with `foo.*`. The third will get all messages (with routing keys starting with foo.); the others will only get messages with their respective keys.

A direct exchange could also be used; it requires a complete match on the routing key.

You should probably work through all the [RabbitMQ tutorials](http://www.rabbitmq.com/getstarted.html) to understand the different exchange types before asking more questions here.